# Creating event-driven SQL scripts

Tags: oracle, plsql, event-handling

I am creating a database that stores GPS data.  As soon as the database updates with a data point , I want the server to check to see if that point is within a certain area and send a message or update another database (haven't decided what action it should take yet).  Is this event-driven operation possible in PL/SQL?  I am only familiar with passive querying and running scheduled scripts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes there is such feature called [database triggers](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/triggers.htm#LNPLS020). On insert or update (actually there are much more event types) of the data you can check if some conditions are met and call PL/SQL procedure to handle the event.